# storing .pem and .key files as strings in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, pem

I am trying to allow users to store .pem and .key file text string in my rails database, but when i try to read them using OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new and OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new, I get the following error: OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pem key` you can use this simple way:

```
# Create pem key
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
# Save key
s = pkey.to_s
# Read key by load text key content to s variable, then:
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(s)
```

But with `X.509 key` you have to fill some extra informations to save:

```
# Create X.509 key
xkey = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
# Fill some fields
xkey.version = 2
xkey.serial = 0
xkey.not_before = Time.now
xkey.not_after = Time.now + 3600
xkey.public_key = key.public_key
xkey.sign key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new
# Save key
s = xkey.to_s
# Read key by load text key content to s variable, then:
xkey = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(s)
```

And all errors will go out of your code : D

Comment: Thank you for this, although i have a question. I had the key stored as a string in an environment variable, it wasn't until i added to `.to_s` to my environment variable `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV["EXAMPLE"].to_s)` that i could get it to work. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure about ENV variable type, but to_s to make sure it will be string variable!